# SQL server Rex fetch string in wildcard

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

For example, I have got a string with table name and the schema like:

```
[dbo].[statistical]
```

How can fetch just the table name `statistical` out from this string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [`PARSENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is used for:

```
SELECT PARSENAME('[dbo].[statistical]', 1)
SELECT PARSENAME('[adventureworks].[dbo].[statistical]', 1)
SELECT PARSENAME('[adventureworks]..[statistical]', 1)
SELECT PARSENAME('[statistical]', 1)
SELECT PARSENAME('dbo.statistical', 1)
-- all examples return 'statistical'
```

Comment: Great! How about if it is not.table, for example (prefix).(nameIneed) this format?

Comment: It'll work as long as it is a valid SQL Server identifier e.g. `dbname..tablename` will give you `tablename`, `tablename` will give you `tablename`, etc. Round brackets will NOT work.

Comment: @NewPy If answer helped you solve your issue, you should accept it (green check amrk on the left)

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively try this:

```
declare @s varchar(100) = 'asd.stadfa';

select reverse(substring(s, 1, charindex('.', s) - 1)) from (
    select reverse(@s) s
) a
```

`charindex` returns first occurence of character, so you reverse initial string to make last dot first. Then you just use substring to extract first part of reversed string, which is what you are looking for. Finally, you need to apply `reverse` one more time to reverse back extracted string :)